# Strange COUNT(*) issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(J.id) as total,
     (3959 * acos (cos ( radians(J.lat) )* cos( radians( UserM.userLat ) )* cos( radians( UserM.userLng ) - radians(j.lng) )+ sin ( radians(J.lat) )* sin( radians( UserM.userLat ) ))) AS distance
FROM doctors J
LEFT JOIN members UserM on UserM.id = 100
HAVING distance < 10
```

I want to count only doctors that have distance < 10 from user but instead of getting (eg. total = 100) I get the following table:

```
total distance
208   2.4766406249672794
```

this is not right because these are all my rows in table 'doctors'. Am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose it's truly impossible that all 208 doctors are within 10 $UNITS of distance from user 100? Have you tried writing a query that shows the distance of each doctor to this user?

Comment: yes if i add "GROUP BY J.id" i get the distance of each doctor inside this distance < 10 (it returns eg.10 results). the issue is with COUNT(*). I want to get these 10 doctors from COUNT but I get full table rows count (208).

Comment: Since MySQL 5.7 there is a new spatial function.  Please provide also a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look to be a particularly well formed query, but the crux is the `HAVING` clause only makes sense within the scope of a `GROUP BY` statement.

So you can do this two ways:

1. Calculate the distance within a subquery, then take a count from that using a `WHERE` clause to limit to cases where the `distance` is less than 10
2. Use a `CASE` statement within a `SUM` to count only if the `distance` is less than 10.

Since you are using MySQL 5.7, you should be able to take advantage of the distance functions.  I'm not sure what units your desired result is using, but `ST_Distance_Sphere` will return meters:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      J.Id
     ,ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(J.Lat,J.Lng),POINT(UserM.userLat,UserM.userLng)) AS distance
    FROM 
      members UserM
    CROSS JOIN
      doctors J
    WHERE
      UserM.id = 100
  ) x
WHERE
  distance < /* however many meters radius required */
```

Using your original calculation:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      J.Id
     ,3959 * acos
        (
          cos(radians(J.lat)) * cos(radians(UserM.userLat)) * cos(radians(UserM.userLng) - radians(j.lng))
            + sin(radians(J.lat)) * sin(radians(UserM.userLat))
        ) AS distance
    FROM 
      members UserM
    CROSS JOIN
      doctors J
    WHERE
      UserM.id = 100
  ) x
WHERE
  distance < 10
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you very much! I have geospatial but it's a bit hard to get the result so I tried with lat,lng instead of POINT. Could you create the above sql syntax using 2 POINTs (1 doctor - 1 user) geospatial?